# akka - How to get results from master after all workers report back?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm following the [akka tutorial](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html). Basically, there is a `listener`, a `master`, and some `worker`s.

```
class Listener extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Report => // message from Master, print result, shutdown system
  }
}

class Master extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Calculate => // ask Workers to calculate
    case Result => // message from Workers, aggregate results. 
                   // if all Workers have reported back, stop self and children,
                   // and send Report message to Listener
}

class Worker extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Calculate => // work, send result back to Master
  }
}
```

My question is how can I get results in `Listener` from outside world? Assume `Report` message is `case class Report(results: Int)`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Do you just want Listener's `receive` to make an external request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Just call the outside setters in `Listener` when it receives `Report` message.

```
object DataHolder {

  private var _data: Int = _

  def data = _data // getter
  def data_= (i: Int): Unit = _data = i // setter
}

class Listener extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Report(results) = {
      DataHolder.data = results // call external setter here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give some more details about your solution? Otherwise the whole post is pointless for any other reader who doesn't understand the original question in the first place, like me. Thanks

Comment: now I understand better, thanks. You could simply define `object DataHolder(var: Int)` with the same exact behaviour. Accessor & mutator are generated automatically by defining the constructor parameter as a var.

Comment: what is the use of dataholder ? if every 1 can take and change data from it ? how can you know that when you read from dataholder that data is accurate ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._

implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
val future = actor ? msg // enabled by the “ask” import
val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[String]
```